# Missing value in modal dialog in edit mode

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, modal-dialog

I'm newbie in Java and PrimeFaces (I have worked only with c# and visual sudio).

When I try to edit a row, column value isn't displayed in modal dialog.
I've tried different solution, same result.
Can someone help me?

```
<ui:include src="/includes/header.xhtml" />

<!-- Container -->
<div  id="container">
    <div class="shell">
        <div id="main" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <br /> <br />

            <form>
                <p:dataTable var="loc" value="#{location.loc}" rowKey="#{loc.code}" id='loca'>
                    <p:column width="100">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" type="button"  id="add" onclick="PF('newDialog').show()" update="Newform:NewLocation"/>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" type="button" update="updForm:updDisplay" onclick="PF('updDialog').show()"  id="edit" ajax="true">
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Code">
                        <h:outputText value="#{loc.code}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Ip">
                        <h:outputText value="#{loc.address}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Descrizione">
                        <h:outputText value="#{loc.description}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </form>

            <p:dialog widgetVar="newDialog" header="Insert Location"  width="430" height="220" modal="true">
                <h:form id="Newform">

                    <p:outputPanel id="NewLocation">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Code" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{loc.Code}"></p:inputText>
                            <h:outputLabel value="description" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{loc.description}"></p:inputText>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Address" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{loc.address}"></p:inputText>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" onclick="newDialog.close()">
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>

            <p:dialog widgetVar="updDialog" header="Location" width="430" height="220" modal="true">
                <h:form id="updForm">
                    <p:outputPanel id="updDisplay">
                        <h:inputHidden value="#{loc.code}" />
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel value="Description" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{loc.description}"></p:inputText>
                            <h:outputLabel value="Address" />
                            <p:inputText value="#{loc.address}"></p:inputText>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <p:commandButton value="Update" onclick="updDialog.close()">
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="updDialog.close()">
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"  />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
```

MangedBean:

```
@ManagedBean (name="Locations")
@SessionScoped
public class Locations {

    @EJB
    cslocationBeanRemote locationsBean;
    private List<cslocationModel> ListLocations;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {}

    public List<cslocationModel> getListLocations() {
        try {
            ArrayList orderBy = new ArrayList();
            orderBy.add(cslocationModel.ORDERcodASC);
            setListLocations((List<cslocationModel>) locationsBean.find(null,
                    null, null, orderBy));
        } catch (Exception ecc) {
            ecc.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ListLocations;
    }

    public void setListLocations(List<cslocationModel> ListLocations) {
        this.ListLocations = ListLocations;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Out of other causes which I do not see as of now, replace `<form>` with `<h:form>`.

Comment: I've replaced <form> with <h:form> but nothing changed. Have you another solution? Please help me.  Thank you.

Comment: What's with the `Locations` managed bean? It's not used even once in XHTML. Please fix the question to be more coherent, make a minimal reproducible example. Also what PrimeFaces version are you using?